# Translate VS Code Editor regular expression in to sed regular expression

Tags: sed, regular-expression

## How to translate from moderen editor regex to `sed` syntax?

Seasoned developer, but complete `sed` noob here, thank you for looking.

- Working on Pop OS Linux 20.04 LTS
- I "cook up" my regular expressions in VS Code as it matches real-time as you key in patterns, very handy!
- Attempting to edit an XML with `sed` in my Dockerfile.
- I have my pattern matching in VS Code, but for the life of me can't seem to find the right `sed` command syntax.
- Rewritten my regex 3 different ways, process of elimination isn't working.  Cannot find what concept/syntax I'm missing here.

#### XML Before

```xml
<!-- HTTP Connector from upstream proxy -->
<Connector executor="tomcatConnectorThreadPool" port="8081" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
            connectionTimeout="3000" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" bindOnInit="false"
            scheme="http" proxyPort="80" />
```

#### XML After (What I'm going after)

```xml
<!-- HTTP Connector from upstream proxy -->Hello World
```

#### My Regex that works in VS Code

Search Pattern

```
(<!-- HTTP Connector from upstream proxy -->)(^.*)(^.*)(^.*)
```

Replace Pattern

*VS Code back-reference = `$1`*

```
$1Hello World
```

#### `sed` failures

Guessing why these don't work.

1. Sorta hairy regex, can't interpret special characters?

   ```bsh
   sed -E 's/(<!-- HTTP Connector from upstream proxy -->\n)([<.\w="\-\s\/>]*$)/\1Hello World/g' path/to/xml.xml
   ```
2. Sub-sub references aren't legal?

   ```bsh
   sed -E 's/(<!-- HTTP Connector from upstream proxy -->\n)((^.*\n){3})/\1Hello World/g' path/to/xml.xml
   ```
3. Not sure why this doesn't work?

   ```bsh
   sed -E 's/(<!-- HTTP Connector from upstream proxy -->)\n(^.*)\n(^.*)\n(^.*)/\1Hello World/g' path/to/xml.xml
   ```

How to express these regular expressions in to proper `sed` command syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you seem to be attempting to match across multiple newlines. Your regex:

```
(<!-- HTTP Connector from upstream proxy -->)(^.*)(^.*)(^.*)
```

This isn't something that would work in any of the regular expression flavors I know. Your VSCode tool seems to be using a regex flavor where multiple `^` implicitly mean "match across newlines". Most *nix utilities work on "records" (lines) defined by a trailing `\n` character. You need tricks to get them to match across multiple lines.

Since you are on Linux, which means you have GNU `sed`, you could do this:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/^(<!-- HTTP Connector from upstream proxy -->)\n([^\n]*\n){3}/\1Hello World\n/' file.xml 
<!-- HTTP Connector from upstream proxy -->Hello World
```

Or, in your case, the much shorter:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/^(<!--[^\n]*)\n([^\n]*\n){3}/\1Hello World\n/' file.xml 
<!-- HTTP Connector from upstream proxy -->Hello World
```

The trick here is the `-z` which makes `sed` slurp the entire file and treat it as one "record". Then, we tell it to find a `<!--` at the beginning of the record and capture that as `\1` (you need parentheses to capture groups), and then match the longest stretch of non-newline characters until a newline (`[^\n]*\n`) and then three more lines (lines means non-newline characters followed by a newline: `([^\n]*\n){3}`).

For this task, I wouldn't use a regex at all, just use the line numbers:

```
$ sed '1s/$/Hello world!/; 2d;3d;4d' file.xml 
<!-- HTTP Connector from upstream proxy -->Hello world!
```